# An alternative phrase or sentence for "With reference to the subject above"?

Tags: synonyms, formality, politeness, letter-writing

I have been using the following sentence for all my official communication, but I have become bored by its monotony.

> With reference to the subject above

I am looking for a total change over of my starting phrase. Is there a better way to begin an official communication?

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

- As regards to the above-mentioned subject
- Regarding the subject mentioned above
- With respect to the subject perviously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a total change over of my starting phrase. Why should i refer to the subject at the first place when it is already in the subject. Is`nt it formal to start the body of the note directly??

Comment: I see your point, it all depends on how you structure your official letter, what you mention in the subject and the reference you probably have to make to past communications. In my experience  official communications/letters tent to be quite rigid in structure and wording used.

Comment: @user73787 I don't know what you are looking for, because these examples are the best. and if you are not pleased with them you should provide more context, so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a subject in a note or an email then why not just write as normal without referencing the subject line directly?  You should assume that people are reading your subject line.

If you are assuming they are not then that type of person probably has little chance reading your communication.  So I would write your body as if the subject line were not there, but staying on subject.  My advice - delete that phrase from your letters and don't find an alternative.

Comment: Yes i`ll do it hereon. Even i got bored of the monotony in my communication. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the subject line already contains what the letter is in reference to it would be verbose to say "with reference to the subject above".  You could simply start the letter by continuing that thought.   For example if the subject line was "JUDY WILL NOT BE AT SCHOOL TODAY", then you could start the letter with, "Judy has taken ill and will be unable to attend her classes today..." because this is a logical continuation of the subject line without unnecessary repetition just for the cause of trying to sound official.

Answer (score 0):

How about....Just wanted to be sure that you received my earlier communication/message/feedback/input/etc.
That way, you are simply confirming in a nice manner that whatever was being referenced has been reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

Re: The Subject Above

(re = regarding)